# How to use Homebrew for converting PDF to HTML?

Tags: pdf-to-html

I just someone say to use homebrew for converting PDF to HTML. I was able to download everything, but I'm not sure how to execute it. Can someone give me the step-by-step?

Comment: Looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). :)

Answer (score 0):

[Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is a package manager for Mac OS X. You could compare it to [Macports](https://www.macports.org/), and [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/).

If you want to convert a PDF into HTML, you could install a program or use a free online converter. Just google "[PDF to HTML converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=PDF%20to%20HTML%20converter)" for a handful of converters.

---

The command to launch Homebrew is

```
$ brew
```

The dollar sign means bash, or terminal. Don't include it when writing the command.